# ASP .NET / Read Only Session / Allows Writing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I notice this post on a similar topic:

[ASP.NET -> WCF concurrency problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767258/asp-net-wcf-concurrency-problem/17593422#17593422)

I just went ahead and added the:

HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);

directive to my HttpModule in the AuthenticateRequest event.  Later on, in my handling code, I call:

HttpContext.Current.Session["value"] = "1";

This set succeeds and the value is there on the next request.  Does anyone have any idea why I don't get an exception thrown here?  I am using MVC 5, .NET 4.5 and used Visual Studio 2013 to compile my application in debug mode.

Comment: Testing has shown that despite the directive, .NET is only allowing a user to request a single activity at a time.  So there is still a write-lock on the session object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think maybe `AuthenticateRequest` is a bit too late to set this. Try setting it in `BeginRequest` instead.

ref the Internet (e.g. http://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/15/programmatically-changing-session-state-behavior-in-asp-net-4-0/) and [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)